# Populate table with JSON list without knowing what the properties are

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm receiving a `JSON` list from server that could contain ***any number of properties of any name***. I need to show that list on my page. Populating a table when you know the names of properties is easy, but for this one I'm totally lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

**HTML:**

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in resultData[0]">
          {{header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in resultData">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
          {{cell}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is a [`sample`](http://plnkr.co/edit/0xD0Z9pwBb9bmAXCknAn?p=preview)